# Merge these two MySQL queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is the task at hand: I have a db table named 'reports', one of the columns in this table is 'submitted_by'. This column contains the username of the person who submitted the report.

Now, what I need to do is display a list of usernames ordered by the number of reports they've posted. So something like this should come out:

User  |  Reports

---

Mark  |  25

---

John  |  18

---

Mary  |  7

etc.

I have written this PHP/MySQL code to do this, it's pretty straightforward but I was wondering if these could be merged into 1 query. Also, would that gain much in terms of efficiency?

```
$users=array();

$result=mysql_query("select id,submitted_by from reports group by submitted_by");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result1=mysql_query("select id,submitted_by from reports where submitted_by='$row[submitted_by]' ");
    $users[$row[submitted_by]]=mysql_num_rows($result1);
}

arsort($users);
```

And then just echo each element from `$users`.

Comment: You don't need two queries, just add a `COUNT(*) AS 'number_of_reports'` to your initial query's SELECT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$users = array();

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, submitted_by, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM reports GROUP BY submitted_by ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $users[$row['submitted_by']] = $row['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Can someone give me an idea about how much faster this works than my original code, or how I would go about testing that?

Comment: To test this you can create large database with hundreds of thousands of records, or else you won't see the difference. Then test like this:
`$start = microtime();

$users = array();

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id, submitted_by, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM reports GROUP BY submitted_by ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $users[$row['submitted_by']] = $row['cnt'];
}

$end = microtime();

echo 'Run time: ' . ($end - $start) . ' microseconds';
`

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = array();

$result = mysql_query("
SELECT id,submitted_by, COUNT(*) as amount 
FROM reports 
GROUP BY submitted_by
ORDER BY amount DESC
");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $users[$row['submitted_by']] = $row['amount'];

// arsort($users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT id, submitted_by, COUNT(*) as numbers FROM reports GROUP BY submitted_by ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table><tr><th>User</th><th>Reports</th></tr><tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo "<td>$row[submitted_by]<td>";
  echo "<td>$row[numbers]<td>";

}

echo "</tr></table>"
```